# You can specify RecordType in the package/retrieve it with SFDX, but it won't include Fields unless you retrieve them too. Is there a way around that?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli

I believe the same applies to profiles/permission sets. I want to be surgical with my retrieval so I only deploy what I want. If I retrieve record types, however, I need to include the Custom Object or the necessary fields.

Including all the fields is too tedious since all the Custom Fields we want to push are usually net new and don't include existing picklist values that we may want to remove from or add to the new record types. However if I include the custom object it retrieves all the record types in that object and requires a tedious, manual extraction of only the record types I want.

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. Depending on your development process, some options are available.

Change Sets can be used to specify just the fields and record types you want to retrieve or deploy, then you can use that to deploy to other Sandboxes or Production either directly (via Outbound Change Sets) or indirectly (via sfdx or another tool).

Scratch Orgs use source tracking to pick up new changes. You can use this to selectively retrieve record types and fields by making the modifications you want. In the future, you'll be able to use a similar process with Sandboxes, though I'd still recommend Scratch Orgs as your go-to.

First Generation Packages (1GP) are another decent choice. You can build exactly the selection you want (with all dependencies automatically included), and then retrieve that package to get just the elements you want. I've used this quite successfully in the past, you may want to give it a try.

If it's just a matter of delta installations/continuous delivery stuff, consider using Unlocked Packages. They are upgradeable, like Managed Packages, and also *downgradeable*, and can perform delta operations (i.e. delete metadata, change metadata, and add metadata).

Your package.xml is free to specify record types and custom fields without the object as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Opportunity.RecordType1</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>Opportunity.Field1__c</members>
    <members>Opportunity.Field2__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
  </types>
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thought you might find this interesting:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/335250/38277

recordtypes named the same as a salesprocess end up in the business process folder.
using source retrieve.