# Why are my recordtypes not being updated, they are going into the wrong folder

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, cli

I have a CLI situation whereby the recordtypes I make changes too are not being updated on a retrieve.
I cannot find flaws in my process, I change the connected org correctly
my XML has the fields, recordtypes business processes and the profiles etc.

The RTs just do not get updated.

UPDATE: THEY ARE... being DL'd into the business processes folder. Not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I found the reason for the incorrect folder location.
Either that or I have broken my VSCode and CLI build???

so what is happening is the recordtypes that are named the same as the business processes (Sales Process) are conflicting some how and causing the recordtypes of the same **exact** name to be retrieved into the businessProcesses folder.

EDIT: Also if they are named the same they are not deploying at all, causing weird behaviors.
Both retrieve and deploy advise everything is working OK but... See pic .. note the folder the RT is landing in

[image]
So I have logged an issue in GIT

**The workaround is to rename the Sales Processes to something different than the RecordType names.**